# How to have duplicate module name in a different folder?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I want to nest my modules like this

```
payment
   contract
   impl
transaction
   contract
   impl
```

i.e. `payment:contract, payment:impl, transaction:contract, transaction:impl`
But gradle complains about there being duplicate impl module (and contract)

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/impl_debug.kotlin_module'.
```

how can I do this, without renaming it to `transaction:transaction-contract` or not nesting?